# Как запустить новую активность из фрагмента?

Tags: android-fragment, android, java, activity

Здравствуйте. Главная активность содержит ViewPager, в котором 3 фрагмента, их можно пролистать.

Мне из фрагмента нужно запустить новую активность, а как сделать не знаю. Создавал `intent` в Main и контекст (Context c = this;), через функцию (отдельно написал) передавал во фрагмент, а там запускал новую активность при нажатии на кнопку, но приложение закрывается.

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему.

Comment: написать запрос в гугл на много быстрее, чем написать вопрос тут    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20start%20activity%20from%20fragment&safe=off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class));
```